# Cannot send POST request to Spring Resource server

Tags: spring-boot, react-redux, axios, spring-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot `ResourceServer`, and a React client application. I am trying to send a `POST` request to one of the server endpoints (which has the `@CrossOrigin` annotation btw.), however, I am getting this error in the console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/search' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
>   does not have HTTP ok status.

The preflight request returns a 401 Http status, and I don't know why.

The response headers for the preflight request look like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 20 Oct 2019 17:23:54 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

My preflight request headers look like this:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/movie-search
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36
```

I am using Axios to send the request (if that matters). Anyone knows what's going on here?

Comment: 401 error response seem like you're not properly applied auth mechanism. Your request should contains an Authorization header like so: `Authorization: Bearer <token>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops...my HTTPSecurity config looked like this:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HTTPMethod.POST, "/api/search").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and().httpBasic()
```

instead of this:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/search").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and().httpBasic()
```